# SelectInput react admin to filter duplicate values in choices and display only unique values

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using react-admin SelectInput and uses name as options but there are in the list that has the same name so the option shows duplicate values. I have tried doing research about filtering duplicate values but I can't seem to make it work.

My data looks like this:

```
data: [{name: "car1",id: 1,}, {name: "car1",id: 2,}, {name: "car2",id: 3,}]
```

Select options will display: car1, car 1, car 2
I want to display no duplicate: car1, car2

Here is my code:

```
<SelectInput optionText={<Choice/>}/>

const Choice = ({...record}) => {
    return(
        <span>{`${record && record.record.carName}`}</span>
    )
}
```

It allows me to play with the select options below like this and it display "test" so I think it can be done here but I cant find a good logic to implement the filter. Anyone has any idea? I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
 `${record && record.record.carName}` !== 'car1'  ?  <span>test</span> : null
```

Comment: I would suggest filtering out the data before passing it to `<SelectInput />`. Instead of filtering it within the choice itself.

Answer (score 1):

You may filter with Set. Set stores only unique values. We filter the data based on whether the name already exists in the Set or not. I hope you don't care about the id. As the first item will remain and the last items will be removed as duplicates. Hope the idea is clear.

```
    let s = new Set();
    let newData =  data.filter(d => {
      if (!s.has(d.name)) {
        s.add(d.name);
        return d;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you guys! I only thought of doing it in the choices since I feel like it's a bit more complicated to implement filter in the data with react-admin but I'll try and see if I can make it work

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is that there are no duplicates in the selection, I would suggest that you filter them before sending them to `SelectInput`.

You can do this by the following:

```js
const data = [{name: "car1",id: 1,}, {name: "car1",id: 2,}, {name: "car2",id: 3,}];

const uniqueChoices = data.reduce((acc, choice) => {
  if (acc.some(item => item.name === choice.name) {
    return acc;
  }
  return [...acc, item]
}, []);

<SelectInput choices={uniqueChoices} />
```